# How to remove or eliminate all dictionary which contains one list value from a list of dictionaries?

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries and I am looking to remove or eliminate all the dictionaries which contain one list-value from each dictionary in that list . This is an example of a dictionary which has one list-value `({'10.48.18.47': ['07:46:06']})`. This is an example of list of dictionaries:

```
[{'10.0.0.155': ['19:48:46', '20:15:46', '19:49:37', '20:15:08', '19:48:46', '19:47:30', '19:49:13', '20:15:50', '19:45:34', '19:45:33', '19:49:13', '19:49:16', '19:49:36', '19:50:02', '19:54:25', '20:15:06', '19:45:25', '20:15:49', '19:55:10', '19:47:33'], '192.168.1.240': ['16:23:40', '16:23:39', '16:23:20'], '192.168.0.242': ['20:14:07', '20:14:09']}, {}, {'10.48.18.47': ['07:46:06']}, {}, {'0.0.0.0': ['21:19:02', '21:45:21', '21:22:04', '21:18:53', '21:38:47', '21:22:52', '21:38:49', '21:22:05', '21:18:55', '21:22:03', '21:18:45', '21:19:01', '21:22:53', '21:18:25', '21:38:51', '21:22:09', '21:18:15'], '192.168.1.193': ['20:09:24', '20:33:57', '20:09:13', '20:09:39', '20:09:29', '20:03:06', '20:09:33', '20:33:58', '20:09:19', '20:09:38', '20:09:37', '20:18:28', '20:09:17', '20:09:22', '20:33:59', '20:29:53', '20:07:47', '20:09:36', '20:18:29', '20:03:04', '20:34:00'], '172.16.12.31': ['18:57:32'], '192.168.1.120': ['20:43:06', '20:43:05', '20:43:04'], '192.168.1.186': ['20:18:36']}]
```

This is my code:

```
My_list = [mhist, mhist1,mhist2,mhist3,mhist4]

print (My_list)

while {} in My_list:

    My_list.remove({})

for dect in My_list:

    count = sum(len(v) for v in dect.values())

    print (count)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this -

```
d = [{'10.0.0.155': ['19:48:46', '20:15:46', '19:49:37', '20:15:08', '19:48:46', '19:47:30', '19:49:13', '20:15:50', '19:45:34', '19:45:33', '19:49:13', '19:49:16', '19:49:36', '19:50:02', '19:54:25', '20:15:06', '19:45:25', '20:15:49', '19:55:10', '19:47:33'], '192.168.1.240': ['16:23:40', '16:23:39', '16:23:20'], '192.168.0.242': ['20:14:07', '20:14:09']}, {}, {'10.48.18.47': ['07:46:06']}, {}, {'0.0.0.0': ['21:19:02', '21:45:21', '21:22:04', '21:18:53', '21:38:47', '21:22:52', '21:38:49', '21:22:05', '21:18:55', '21:22:03', '21:18:45', '21:19:01', '21:22:53', '21:18:25', '21:38:51', '21:22:09', '21:18:15'], '192.168.1.193': ['20:09:24', '20:33:57', '20:09:13', '20:09:39', '20:09:29', '20:03:06', '20:09:33', '20:33:58', '20:09:19', '20:09:38', '20:09:37', '20:18:28', '20:09:17', '20:09:22', '20:33:59', '20:29:53', '20:07:47', '20:09:36', '20:18:29', '20:03:04', '20:34:00'], '172.16.12.31': ['18:57:32'], '192.168.1.120': ['20:43:06', '20:43:05', '20:43:04'], '192.168.1.186': ['20:18:36']}]

for dct in d:
    for key in dct.copy():
        if len(dct[key]) <= 1:
           dct.pop(key,None)
```

The reason some `keys` with length less then 1 was left because there were multiple dicts inside the list

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
>>> data = [{'10.0.0.155': ['19:48:46', '20:15:46', '19:49:37', '20:15:08', '19:48:46', '19:47:30', '19:49:13', '20:15:50', '19:45:34', '19:45:33', '19:49:13', '19:49:16', '19:49:36', '19:50:02', '19:54:25', '20:15:06', '19:45:25', '20:15:49', '19:55:10', '19:47:33'], '192.168.1.240': ['16:23:40', '16:23:39', '16:23:20'], '192.168.0.242': ['20:14:07', '20:14:09']}, {}, {'10.48.18.47': ['07:46:06']}, {}, {'0.0.0.0': ['21:19:02', '21:45:21', '21:22:04', '21:18:53', '21:38:47', '21:22:52', '21:38:49', '21:22:05', '21:18:55', '21:22:03', '21:18:45', '21:19:01', '21:22:53', '21:18:25', '21:38:51', '21:22:09', '21:18:15'], '192.168.1.193': ['20:09:24', '20:33:57', '20:09:13', '20:09:39', '20:09:29', '20:03:06', '20:09:33', '20:33:58', '20:09:19', '20:09:38', '20:09:37', '20:18:28', '20:09:17', '20:09:22', '20:33:59', '20:29:53', '20:07:47', '20:09:36', '20:18:29', '20:03:04', '20:34:00'], '172.16.12.31': ['18:57:32'], '192.168.1.120': ['20:43:06', '20:43:05', '20:43:04'], '192.168.1.186': ['20:18:36']}]
>>> final_data = []
>>> for d in data:
...   if len(d.values()) > 1:
...     final_data.append(d)
...
>>> final_data
[{'10.0.0.155': ['19:48:46', '20:15:46', '19:49:37', '20:15:08', '19:48:46', '19:47:30', '19:49:13', '20:15:50', '19:45:34', '19:45:33', '19:49:13', '19:49:16', '19:49:36', '19:50:02', '19:54:25', '20:15:06', '19:45:25', '20:15:49', '19:55:10', '19:47:33'], '192.168.1.240': ['16:23:40', '16:23:39', '16:23:20'], '192.168.0.242': ['20:14:07', '20:14:09']}, {'0.0.0.0': ['21:19:02', '21:45:21', '21:22:04', '21:18:53', '21:38:47', '21:22:52', '21:38:49', '21:22:05', '21:18:55', '21:22:03', '21:18:45', '21:19:01', '21:22:53', '21:18:25', '21:38:51', '21:22:09', '21:18:15'], '192.168.1.193': ['20:09:24', '20:33:57', '20:09:13', '20:09:39', '20:09:29', '20:03:06', '20:09:33', '20:33:58', '20:09:19', '20:09:38', '20:09:37', '20:18:28', '20:09:17', '20:09:22', '20:33:59', '20:29:53', '20:07:47', '20:09:36', '20:18:29', '20:03:04', '20:34:00'], '172.16.12.31': ['18:57:32'], '192.168.1.120': ['20:43:06', '20:43:05', '20:43:04'], '192.168.1.186': ['20:18:36']}]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your interest. I can see there is two dictionaries which contain one list value weren't removed or eliminated at the end of the list of dictionaries. Can you please help me to remove them as well.

Comment: Those dictionaries are "'172.16.12.31': ['18:57:32']" and "'192.168.1.186': ['20:18:36']"